# How can I can set the elevation on an EditText inside a TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I had an edit text like this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/hcNumEditText"
        style="@style/AppTheme.TextField"
        android:hint="@string/hc_number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="300dp"
        android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_normal"/>
```

Which worked as expected, but when I wrapped it in a TextInputLayout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/hcNumTextInputLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/footer"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_max="300dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/elevation_normal">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hcNumEditText"
        style="@style/AppTheme.TextField"
        android:hint="@string/hc_number"
        android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_normal"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

There is not shadow from the elevation, what gives?
I have padding added to the TextInputLayout to make room for the shadow, but it still doesn't appear...

Comment: Try `android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_normal"` in `TextInputLayout`

Answer (score -4):

Use

```
android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_normal"
```

Inside `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayoutAnd` . Also you need to define **elevation_normal** in **dimens.xml**.

Comment: your answer is same as above comment.

Comment: I tried this, if you apply an elevation to the TextInputLayout then the shadow emits from the boundaries of the layout not the EditText. the TextInputLayout's boundaries are taller to make room for the hint.